# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

Hay algunas ventas que ya no existen y quiero borrar los Abonos que se hicieron con esas ventas inexistentes, mi código fue este:

```
DELETE Abonos_Creditos 
FROM Abonos_Creditos ac
LEFT JOIN Venta_Gas vg
ON ac.id_credito=vg.idVenta
WHERE ac.id_credito is null;
```

Y me da el siguiente error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Alguien sabe cual es la forma correcta de ejecutar esta sentencia?

Comment: Bievenido a StackOverflow. Tienes el nombre de la tabla antes del `FROM`. Prueba de esta manera: **`DELETE 
FROM Abonos_Creditos ac
LEFT JOIN Venta_Gas vg
ON ac.id_credito=vg.idVenta
WHERE ac.id_credito is null;`**

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis correcta es:

> DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
>       [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
>       [WHERE where_condition]
>       [ORDER BY ...]
>       [LIMIT row_count]

El nombre de la tabla solo va después del "FROM" quedando:

```
DELETE FROM Abonos_Creditos ac
LEFT JOIN Venta_Gas vg
ON ac.id_credito=vg.idVenta
WHERE ac.id_credito is null;
```